# too few arguments to function `void GenerateSecretNumber(int, int)'

Tags: c++, function, arguments, prototype

**Function Prototype**

```
void GenerateSecretNumber(int rang, int x);
```

**Function <strike>Declaration</strike> Definition**

```
void GenerateSecretNumber(int rang, int x){

  int secret = 0;
  cout<<"Computer is calculating a random secret number in the given range ...";
  srand(time(NULL));
  secret = rand()%(rang+1);
  cout<<"Done!"<<endl<<endl;
 }
```

Comment: well, we need to see how you call that function

Comment: And you *do* call the function with two arguments? The error message, if you look closely, contain the file name and line number of the location of the error, so you can easily find it.

Comment: BTW, `x` is unused, you should probably remove it from declaration & definition.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` should be called only once, not for each `rand()` call.

Answer (score 0):

This *definition* is fine. The problem is when you're calling `GenerateSecretNumber()` function.

While calling, you need to pass the exact number of arguments. something like

```
int p = 5;
int q = 10;
```

and

```
GenerateSecretNumber(p, q);
```

However, I see no logical reason to pass and accept the second parameter `x`. :-) You never used it inside your function. You can consider redefining your function signature as `void GenerateSecretNumber(int rang)`.

I'm suspecting, maybe, currently you used something like `GenerateSecretNumber(p);` only.

Comment: FWIW, you can also do `GenerateSecretNumber(5, 10);` directly. Important is that you pass two integer parameters.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis absolutely sir, i mentioned that in my anser. but is that the reason for the DV?

Comment: I didn't downvote (if that is what you mean with DV), so I don't know. I only wanted to clarify your answer to the "questioner".

Comment: That is what downvoters often do. I don't understand it, but it happens a lot.